# Getting cannot read style of undefined when load the component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have build one custom carousel component and it works well. But the issue is when i load it, it throws

"  This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Error during LWC component connect phase: [Cannot read property 'style' of undefined]"

here is my code:

```
<template>
<div  class="slds-carousel__panels slideshow-container w3-content slds-align_absolute-center slds-section" style="transform:translateX(-0%)">
   
        <template for:each={result} for:item="res" for:index="index">
         <div class="mySlides fade w3-container " key={res.Id}>

             <div data-index={index} 
                  class="slds-carousel__image img w3-container slds-align_absolute-center slds-grid slds-grid_vertical" style="height:240px;width:400px;">
                  <div class="slds-p-vertical_small"></div>
                 
                  <p class="ex1">Things to do for quick approval</p>
                  <div class="slds-p-vertical_small"></div>
                 
                  <div class="slds-col">
                   
                 
                
                    <span class="slds-col">{res.Comments__c}</span>
                  </div>
                     
                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-col">
                    <a class="slds-button slds-button_brand" href="javascript:void(0);">Read More</a>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         
     </template>
       
   
</div>
<div class="slds-p-bottom_medium"></div>
<div style="text-align:center" >
    <template if:true={numbers}>
<template for:each={numbers} for:item="num" for:index="index">
   
    <span class="dot" onclick={currentSlide} data-carousel={num} key={num}></span> 
  
</template>
```

Javascript code:

```
    import {
    LightningElement,
    track,
    api,
    wire
} from 'lwc';
import getBanners from '@salesforce/apex/test.getBanners';
import Offers from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/test';
export default class test extends LightningElement {
    @track result;
    @track target=[];
    @track slideIndex=0;
  @track sfdcBaseURL;
    @track slides;
    @track dots;
   @track numbers=[];
   @track carousel=0;
   @track hasRendered = false;
   @track brandName=[];


   @wire(getBanners, {
       
})
wiredResult({
    error,
    data
}) { 
    if(data) {
        this.result=data;
        console.log('Offers'+Offers);
        console.log('RESULT LENGTH'+this.result.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.result.length; i++) {
            this.numbers.push(i);
            this.brandName.push(this.result[i].Brand__r.Name);
            console.log(' this.brandName'+ JSON.stringify(this.brandName));
          }
       
          console.log('this.numbers Wired'+this.numbers.length);
       
        this.error = undefined;
       
    }
};
       
       
       
   connectedCallback(){
   
   }

  
    renderedCallback() {
       this.addStyle();
     //  setTimeout(() => this.slideIndex=0, 5000);
this.slideIndex=0;
       // console.log('this.numbers Rendered Call Back'+this.numbers.length);
        this.showSlides();
       // setTimeout(() => this.showSlides(), 2000);
     //
        //this.startSlideShow();   
       // let self = this;
      // let self = this;
       // setTimeout(self.startSlideShow(this.carousel).bind(self), 3000);
      
      // 
      //this.slideIndex=0;
      //this.startSlideShow(this.carousel);
     //
     // setInterval(() => this.startSlideShow(this.carousel), 5000);
    }

    
     
   
addStyle() {
    this.sfdcBaseURL = window.location.origin;
    console.log('this.sfdcBaseURL'+this.sfdcBaseURL);
    const divs = this.template.querySelectorAll('.img');
    console.log('divs length'+divs.length);
    Array.from(divs).forEach(div => {
        const index = Number(div.getAttribute("data-index"));
        
        // Note: change this to whatever property you want
        div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(URL)';
      
      
    });
   
    
}

 showSlides() {
    //console.log('carousel showSlides'+carousel);
    var i;
    //if(this.hasRendered == true){

        this.slides  = this.template.querySelectorAll('.mySlides');
        console.log('slides'+this.slides.length);
       // console.log('slides'+JSON.stringify(this.slides));
        this.dots = this.template.querySelectorAll('.dot');
        console.log('dots'+this.dots.length);
        for (i = 0; i <  this.slides.length; i++) {
            this.slides[i].style.display = "none";  
            //this.template.querySelector(this.slides[i]).classList.add('displayclass'); 
         }
         this.slideIndex++;
         if (this.slideIndex >  this.slides.length) {this.slideIndex = 1}   
        
  
        
        
        // 
        
        for (i = 0; i <this.dots.length; i++) {
            this.dots[i].className = this.dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
           // this.template.querySelector(this.dots[i]).classList.remove('active'); 
      }
    
      console.log('this.slideIndex'+this.slideIndex);
     
      //console.log('this.slideIndex'+this.slides);
     // if(this.slides[this.slideIndex-1]!=='undefined' && this.slides[this.slideIndex-1]!=null){
         // console.log('inside if');
        //  console.log('inside if'+this.slides[this.slideIndex-1]);
       // setTimeout(() => this.slides[this.slideIndex-1].style.display = "block", 5000);
       console.log('this.slideIndex'+this.slideIndex);
     
        this.slides[this.slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
      // this.template.querySelector(this.slides[this.slideIndex-1]).classList.add('displayBlock'); 
     // }
     // if(this.dots[this.slideIndex-1]!=='undefined' && this.dots[this.slideIndex-1]!=null){
     //   console.log('inside if 1');
      //  console.log('inside if'+this.dots[this.slideIndex-1]);
        this.dots[this.slideIndex-1].className += " active";
       // setTimeout(() => this.dots[this.slideIndex-1].className += " active", 5000);
       // this.template.querySelector(this.dots[this.slideIndex-1]).classList.add('active'); 
     // }
    
     //this.template.querySelector(this.slides[this.slideIndex-1]).classList.add('displayBlock'); 
     //this.template.querySelector(this.dots[this.slideIndex-1]).classList.add('active'); 

    //}
  
    // // Change image every 2 seconds
    setTimeout(() => this.showSlides(), 5000);
  }
  
startSlideShowold(carousel){
    //console.log('this.numbers slide show'+this.numbers.length);
    console.log('carousel slide show'+carousel);
    if(this.numbers){
        if(5> 1){
            setInterval(function() {
            
              if(carousel < 5){
                carousel = carousel + 1;
                
                  this.showSlides(carousel);
              }else{
                carousel = 1;
                 
                  this.showSlides(carousel);
              }
            }, 500);
        }
    }
  
}

startSlideShow(carousel) {
    console.log('carousel slide show'+carousel);
    if (this.numbers && this.numbers.length > 1) {
      
      setInterval(()=>{
        this.showSlides(carousel < this.numbers.length ? carousel++ : 0);
      }, 5000);
    }
   
  }
currentSlide(event){
 
    console.log('this.numbers'+this.numbers);
    var carousel = event.target.dataset.carousel; 
    console.log('carousel'+carousel);
    this.showSlides(carousel);
}


  
}
```

Once i close the error popup, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging here. It's not immediately obvious why you're getting this error. My best guess is: `this.slides[this.slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";`, but that doesn't seem to make sense. What's the last line of console output before you stop? Have you tried using the Break on all exceptions feature of your browser's debugger?

Comment: Thansk sfdcfox. I was able to fix it. The issue was Both methods being in RenderedCallBack were being executed multiple times. When it was being executed first time divs.length ,slides.length and dots.length was zero So i had to put one validation like only if divs.legnth>0 execute the showslides method and it got fixed.